# Prove that reverse=rev

Tags: haskell, equivalent, proof

I have some task to do, but don't know how to do it:

```
reverse, rev :: [a] [a]

reverse [] = []
reverse (x:xs) = reverse xs ++ [x]

rev = aux [] where
    aux ys [] = ys
    aux ys (x:xs) = aux (x:ys) xs
```

"Prove that : reverse=rev"

Your help would be appreciated. Thank you.

PS. I can do it using some example but i think thats not professional

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please add the homework tag.

Comment: You should give some background information to avoid answers which go completely over your head or spend a lot of time explaining things you already know. Specifically: I assume you're taking a class on programming languages, which before giving out this assignment, explained the concept of structural induction - is that correct? If so did you understand it and do you see how this might be applied to this task?

Comment: Just use induction... there are only like 2-3 cases (from a quick glance) for the step.

Comment: Studies-programming in logic.Haskell-but we have just started,so i don't know too much... Prolog was easier;)

What i understand (or think that i do) is:

reverse [] = [] %for empty list we have noting to reverse

reverse (x:xs) = reverse xs ++ [x] %if list is longer we need to take care of its tail-reverse it and add [x] to it, as many times as we get reverse []


% aux checks if element is in list?

rev = aux [] where 

    aux ys [] = ys %if we seek for ys in blank list we get that element

    aux ys (x:xs) = aux (x:ys) xs %do not understand it(i see we take care of tail but nothing more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to prove equivalence directly, I would for each function prove (using induction) that it actually reverses the list. If both of them reverse lists, then they are equivalent.

**Proof sketch:**

We want to prove that rev works for all lists:

**base case** lists of length 0:
*prove that rev [] computes correctly*

**inductive case**:
prove that for any n, rev can reverses any list of length n, assuming rev can reverse any list of length up to n-1

Comment: But what's your definition of "reversing a list"?

Comment: The informal one. Probably should have writen "rev returns the reversed list" instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a sloppy proof by structural induction, but if you want to a proof that handles bottom correctly it is less trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Induction. The base case is trivial. The inductive step shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 1):

Since any list reversing function can only produce any output if given finite lists, we can translate this code into Coq (in which lists are always finite) and prove the desired statement there (ignoring bottom).

This proof is not my own - it is a slightly modified version of a proof from the standard library.

```
Open Scope list_scope.

Require List.
Require Import FunctionalExtensionality.

Section equivalence.

  Variable A : Type.

  (* The reverse function is already defined in the standard library as List.rev. *)
  Notation reverse := (@List.rev A).

  Fixpoint aux (ys l2 : list A) :=
    match l2 with
      nil => ys
      | x :: xs => aux (x :: ys) xs
    end.

  Definition rev : list A -> list A
    := aux nil.

  Lemma aux_rev : forall l l', aux l' l = reverse l ++ l'.
  Proof.
    induction l; simpl; auto; intros.
    rewrite <- List.app_assoc; firstorder.
  Qed.

  Theorem both_equal : reverse = rev.
    extensionality xs.
    unfold rev.
    rewrite aux_rev.
    now rewrite List.app_nil_r.
  Qed.

End equivalence.
```

Comment: You first statement isn't true.  A list reversal function in Haskell might very well generate output even for infinite lists.  Every time you see a cons in the input list you know there will be a cons in the output list.

Comment: @augustss: could you explain that in more detail?  The only output I can imagine for an infinite list is `⊥:⊥` (with cons's nested arbitrarily deep) instead of simply `⊥`.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: @JohnL Yes, I mean a list of conses, where each element is bottom (when the list is infinite).  This is still enough to do interesting things like testing if the length of the list is bigger than some number (using lazy natural numbers).  I'm not saying this is very useful, just that the statement that reverse of an infinite list must return bottom is false.

Comment: Actually, I think the more fundamental objection I should have made is that it's not clear that it's semantically meaningful to talk about reversing an infinite list.

Comment: @RobinGreen It is semantically meaningful to talk about what happens when you apply a function to an infinite list.  And among the functions that reverse the list when applied to a finite list there will be different results when applied to an infinite list.  Trying to just do an inductive proof that covers the finite case is not the right thing for Haskell.  You'll not get a valid proof for Haskell.

Comment: @augustss: thanks very much.  I think I'm finally starting to get an understanding of Haskell.